# IntelliJ Gradle Integration - How to troubleshoot slow gradle reloads

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

IntelliJ seems to gradle reload the world every time I pull in non-major changes from git. There must be some dependency that is causing a slow reload or something.

So I will git pull in my branch's latest changes and then go to intelliJ and there it goes reloading the world again.

How can I troubleshoot what modules are causing this troubling behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Understand that Gradle Build has nothing to do with your CPU Speed or RAM. The reason why the Build gets slower in your PC is due to your Internet Connection. The build can take nearly ~100 MB approx. of data to complete it's process. Even if your Internet Connection is fast and your connection's PING speed is slow, it takes more time. Relax and be patient.